# Calculating expectation values over an observable

Tags: quantum-mechanics, probability

I have a question pertaining to a seemingly (to me) arbitrary, yet necessary distinction one must make when calculating the expectation value of, say, momentum $\hat p$:

I forgot to ask her, but my lecturer made it very clear that when computing this, that the following is necessary:

$$<\hat p> \ = \  m \frac{d}{dt} \ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi* \ \hat x[\psi] \ dx$$

However, why can't it be this?

$$<\hat p> \ = \ m \frac{d}{dt} \ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi \ \hat x[\psi*] \ dx$$

It seems oddly arbitrary that the operator must act on the non-complex conjugate version of the function. Why is this necessary?

Note: A commenter told me this more a case-by-case thing, as position doesn't have such a requirement but momentum does. Could someone care to explain why?

Comment: For the $\hat{x}$ operator, it doesn't matter. For a more complicated operator, it will matter. I assume this definition is supposed to lead you towards the proper definition of the $\hat{p}$ operator; once you've written down the $\hat{p}$ operator, you should be able to convince yourself it matters which one it acts on.

Comment: @JahanClaes So you're saying it's a case-by-case thing?

Comment: I'm saying you should ALWAYS act on the $\psi$, that's the rule. In some cases, if you mistakenly act on the $\psi^*$, you'll get the same answer. But in general we need to choose a consistent rule, and the consistent rule everyone has chosen is it acts on $\psi$.

Comment: @JahanClaes But why? Is there some formal justification for this? I'm confused.

Comment: No, it's a definition. When we write the expression $\langle \hat{x}\rangle$, it has to MEAN something. We DEFINE it to mean $\int \psi^* \hat{x} \psi$. We could have defined it to mean something else, like $\int \hat{x}\psi^*  \psi$, and all our subsequent formulas would just look a little different. It's not really important which one we pick, it's just important that we're consistent, so that every time we write down $\langle\hat x\rangle$ it means the same thing..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the operator you're calculating the expectation value of is an observable, it will be Hermitian and (hence) the expectation value must be real. 
So you might as well take the complex conjugate of the entire expression; it will not change the result.

If the operator is not Hermitian, it does matter on which function the operator acts. 
The default setting is to have the operator acting on $\psi$, not $\psi \ast$. Acting on $\psi\ast$ instead will give the expectation value of the Hermitian adjoint of the operator, which is not at all surprising, but important to keep track of.

Comment: I see. How do I know which operator is Hermitian or not?

Comment: Operators corresponding to observables (momentum, position, energy, ...) are always Hermitian. In many (but not all) realistic cases, any operator of which one would like to calculate the expectation value will be an observable. Usually, you will know when some operator is not Hermitian.